# PHP- Problem passing information between PHP, Angular & HTTP?

Tags: javascript, php, angular, http

I'm working on a Laravel PHP site, and am getting an error when trying to add a user to a cell in a table

The error says:

> An error has occurred adding your contact. If the problem persists, please contact us.

and is displayed in a red 'ribbon' that pops up just below the browser address bar for a few seconds when trying to select a new user from the drop down.

I have seen a couple of similar [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41381642/unexpected-token-in-json-at-position-0) on SO, but can't see how any of the answers apply to what's going on here...

In the HTML, the table column whose cell value I am trying to update is done via a form that pops up in a dialog box when pressing the 'Edit' icon in the cell:

```
<div class="provTaxContacts__row">
    <form [formGroup]="newContactForm" class="provTaxContacts__col provTaxContacts__new-contact">
        <label>Add new contact</label>
        <div class="provTaxContacts__new-contact-fields">
            <input class="provTaxContacts__new-contact-field provTaxContacts__name" [class.error]="newContactFormErrors.contactFirstName" placeholder="First name" type="text" autocomplete="given-name" formControlName="contactFirstName" />
            <input class="provTaxContacts__new-contact-field provTaxContacts__name" [class.error]="newContactFormErrors.contactLastName" placeholder="Last name" type="text" autocomplete="family-name" formControlName="contactLastName" />
            <input class="provTaxContacts__new-contact-field provTaxContacts__email" [class.error]="newContactFormErrors.contactEmail" placeholder="Email address" type="email" autocomplete="email" formControlName="contactEmail" />
            <button class="btn btn-primary provTaxContacts__new-contact-button" type="button" (click)="onNewContactAdd(taxpayer.accountId)">Add contact</button>
            <div *ngIf="addContactLoading" class="spinner-loading"></div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

The `onNewContactAdd()` function that's called when pressing the 'Add Contact' button is defined in a Typescript file called tax-reminder.ts, and as well as handling what happens to the browser on the front-end, it also calls the function `addUserToAccount()` from user.service.ts. It is what's displaying the error in the browser, and is defined with:

```
onNewContactAdd(accountId: number) {
    const firstName = this.newContactForm.get('contactFirstName').value;
    const lastName = this.newContactForm.get('contactLastName').value;
    const email = this.newContactForm.get('contactEmail').value;
    // Reset error states
    this.resetContactFormErrors();

    // Check for form errors
    if (!firstName || Validate.isEmpty(firstName) || !Validate.lettersAndSpaces(firstName)) {
        this.newContactFormErrors.contactFirstName = true;
    } else {
        this.newContactFormErrors.contactFirstName = false;
    }

    if (!lastName || Validate.isEmpty(lastName) || !Validate.lettersAndSpaces(lastName)) {
        this.newContactFormErrors.contactLastName = true;
    } else {
        this.newContactFormErrors.contactLastName = false;
    }

    if (Validate.isEmpty(email) || !Validate.emailRegex.test(email)) {
        this.newContactFormErrors.contactEmail = true;
    } else {
        this.newContactFormErrors.contactEmail = false;
    }

    // If there are any errors at this stage, Don't add
    if (this.newContactFormErrors.contactFirstName || this.newContactFormErrors.contactLastName || this.newContactFormErrors.contactEmail) {
        return
    }

    // Reset errors, just in case there were previous erros that we now know have been resolved
    this.resetContactFormErrors();
    this.addContactLoading = true;
    // If all is valid, send a request to create the new contact
    this.userService.addUserToAccount([{firstName, lastName, email, role: 'FULL'}], 'FULL', accountId)
        .subscribe(
            (response: any) => {
                this.addContactLoading = false;

                // Reset the add contact form so that the user can add more
                this.newContactForm.patchValue({
                    contactFirstName: '',
                    contactLastName: '',
                    contactEmail: '',
                });

                // If the new contact's email address is already in the on-page list do nothing
                if (_.find(this.contacts[accountId], {email})) {
                    return;
                } else {
                    // If the request is succcessful, add the new contact to the list of contacts
                    this.contacts[accountId].push({
                        accountId,
                        email,
                        firstName,
                        groupTag: 'FULL',
                        lastName,
                        provTaxManager: 0,
                                                    provTaxPaymentsContact: 0,
                                                    userId: response.userId,
                                                    //transactionContactId,
                    });
                }
            },
            error => {
                console.log("Error: " + error);
                const message = new Message();
                message.type = MessageType.ERROR;
                message.message = 'An error has occurred adding your contact. If the problem persists please contact us.';
                this.messagingService.emitMessage(message);
            }
        )
}
```

In the browser console, I can see the following output in the Network-> Preview tab:

```
array:9 [
"userId" => 9561
"title" => null
"firstName" => "Shane"
"lastName" => "Williams"
"workPhone" => null
"mobilePhone" => null
"email" => "shane@williams.com"
"userTypeId" => 3
"login" => array:3 [
"loginId" => 9449
"loginName" => "shane@williams.com"
"userId" => 9561
]
]
```

Which shows that the details I entered into the form have been collected, and a new user ID has been assigned.

That output is coming from a `dd()` I have in the `addAccountUser()` PHP function:

```
public function addAccountUser( AddAccountUsersRequest $request )
{
  $users = $request->input('users');
  $type = $request->input('type');
  $accountId = $request->input('accountId');
  
  $userType = $type == 'taxfirm-agent' ? UserType::where('userTypeTag', 'AGENT')->first() : UserType::where('userTypeTag', 'DIRECT')->first();
  $messages = array();
  $hasWarningMessages = false;
  
  try
  {
      DB::beginTransaction();

        foreach ($users as $userRaw)
        {

              $details = array(
                  'firstName' => $userRaw['firstName'],
                  'lastName'  => $userRaw['lastName'],
                  'email'     => $userRaw['email'],
                  'password'  => uniqid(),
                  'userTypeId' => $userType->userTypeId,
                  'accountId' => (!empty($accountId)) ? $accountId : null
              );
        $propertyValues = array();

        // Adding tax agent
        if ($type == 'taxfirm-agent') {
            $group = $userRaw['role'];
            $rv = $this->addTaxfirmAgent($details, $group);
        }
        else if($type == 'taxfirm-direct') {
            $rv = $this->addTaxfirmDirectContact($details);
        }
        else {
            $group = $userRaw['role'];
            $rv = $this->addTaxpayerDirectContact($details, $group);
        }

        DB::commit();
        dd($rv['user']->toArray()); 

        if ($rv['status'] !== 'SUCCESS') {
            if (!isset($messages[$rv['status']])) {
              $messages[$rv['status']] = array(
                'message' => StatusMessage::getMessage($rv['status']),
                'data' => [],
            //dd($messages);
              );
            }

            $messages[$rv['status']]['data'][] = [$userRaw['email'], ucfirst($userRaw['firstName']), ucfirst($userRaw['lastName'])];
        //dd($messages); // success is true at this point, users are null


            if (!$hasWarningMessages)
            {
              $hasWarningMessages = true;
            }
        }
        }
    }
      catch(\Exception $e)
      {
          DB::rollback();
        return response()->json(array(
          'success' => false,
          'exceptionCode' => $e->getCode(),
          'exceptionMessage' => $e->getMessage().' - '.$e->getFile().' - '.$e->getLine(),
          'userId' => $userId // Try returning the userId too...
        ), 400);
      }

      $outputMsg = array();
      foreach ($messages as $value) {
        $outputMsg[] = $value;
      }
      //dd($users);

      return response()->json(array(
        'success' => true,
        'hasWarningMessages' => $hasWarningMessages,
        'result' => $outputMsg,
        //'users' => $rv['user']->user, /*ERF(18/09/2018 @ 1630) Change to userId */
        'userId' => $rv['user']->userId,
      ));
    }
```

I don't fully understand how the JavaScript, PHP & HTTP are all interacting here, or why the PHP debug appears to be showing the new contact created successfully, and yet I still get the error in the browser.

Can anyone point me in the right direction here? Why is the contact seemingly created, and yet I get the error, as well as the contact not being displayed in the drop down box as I am expecting?

**Edit**

So, I think that the issue I'm having here is not to do with the PHP itself- as that function seems to be returning the correct information (the console output given when I added the line `dd($rv['user']->toArray())` at the end of the function showed all of the details for the user I had just added correctly), but rather to do with the Angular that should be updating the front end, to display the new user in the drop down.

That function is defined as follows:

```
this.userService.addUserToAccount([{firstName, lastName, email, role: 'FULL'}], 'FULL', accountId)
.subscribe(
    (response: any) => {
        this.addContactLoading = false;

        // Reset the add contact form so that the user can add more
        this.newContactForm.patchValue({
            contactFirstName: '',
            contactLastName: '',
            contactEmail: '',
        });

        // If the new contact's email address is already in the on-page list do nothing
        if (_.find(this.contacts[accountId], {email})) {
            return;
        } else {
            // If the request is succcessful, add the new contact to the list of contacts
            this.contacts[accountId].push({
                accountId,
                email,
                firstName,
                groupTag: 'FULL',
                lastName,
                provTaxManager: 0,
                provTaxPaymentsContact: 0,
                userId: response.userId,
                //transactionContactId,
            });
       }
    },
    error => {
        console.log("Error: " + error);
        const message = new Message();
        message.type = MessageType.ERROR;
        message.message = 'An error has occurred adding your contact. If the problem persists please contact us.';
        this.messagingService.emitMessage(message);
    }
)
```

I think I need to add a call to reload this page element at the end of the `else` statement in this function... How would I do that?

**Edit**

So, it seems that although the contact appears to be created, the HTTP response I'm getting is actually the error- as I can see the `An error has occurred adding your contact. If the problem persists please contact us.` message in the browser... Why is it that the HTTP response is failing? How can I resolve this?

I added a `console.log()` to display the error in the console, and it's showing the following output:

> unparsable response
>
> Error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

I don't understand where this error is coming from... any ideas?

Comment: Are you returning the 'API' method with a 200 OK response? Can't see that part in your shared code.

Comment: Sorry, I'm very new to PHP- how/ where should I be doing that?

Comment: For some reason, after adding the contact and getting the failure message, if I then refresh the page, the new contact that I've just added is actually displayed in the drop down correctly....

Comment: Sorry, I had missed off the final return statement when pasting the code in earlier- I've just edited my post to add that in.

Comment: I think the root of the problem is that I need to reload the Angular page element after returning the new user in the PHP function... I'm just not sure how to do this- any suggestions?

Comment: It's nothing with PHP - but a REST API problem - make sure you respond the request with a 200 OK status code so Angular detects a success request. Now it seems to detect a fail due to a HTTP status reponse != 200 OK. When refreshing your page - the REST method to retrieve contacts will reflect the newly created one. Normal behaviour... but you need the create method to reflect success upon response... it's not an Angular problem ...

Comment: So do I need to add the 200 status code to the response? How/ where would I do that? (I've not used HTTP before at all...)

Comment: There is the `(response: any) => {....}` part of the function, and an `error => {...}` part, do I need to add a `(response: success) => {...}` part?

Comment: When I click the 'Add contact' button, it seems I am actually getting the HTTP error response- I can see the error message displayed in the browser... Why is this? How can I get the HTTP response to return successfully?